# How can I get the membercount of the group without the telegram bot api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

How can I get the membercount of the group without the telegram bot api?And is there any way to get the membercount of group which I am not admin?plz help me Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get member count of any group but for that, you have to use a third party code telethon, you can find it here:- https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon

Comment: I find the method that get the member of channel,but I can't find the method about group.Is it the same to the channel?

Answer (score 0):

use this `cid = message.chat.id` to get chat/group id

and this `id = message.from_user.id` to get user id